# javascript help using html and calculator

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, calculator

Can someone help me to get the total price of the stock given prices below?? Using the onclick, once someone puts in the number of stocks they want to buy, how do I go about getting the total price of all 3 stocks choosen??

```
    <tr>
        <td><b> SHARE PRICE</b></td>
        <td>$43.93</td>
        <td>$43.87</td>
        <td>$26.33</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<hr>
<br>
<p>
<h3>Important information that you should know about these stocks: </h3>
<ul>
    <li>0.1% of the trade value if the total trade value is less than $10,000</li>
    <li>0.08% of the trade value if the total trade value is greater than or equal to $10,000</li>
    <li>The minimum commission is $5</li>
    <hr>
    <br>
</ul>  

<form name="calculator">

<p> Enter the number of Oracle Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input1"></p> <br>
<p> Enter the number of Microsoft Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input2"></p> <br>
<p> Enter the number of Symantec Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input3"></p> <br
```

Comment: What you've tried so far? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

I would suggest storing the price information as a numeric value somewhere, like in hidden input fields or `data-` attributes on the table cells, and create IDs on those elements that you can associate with the inputs for stock purchases. Then it's just a matter of doing some simple math. Here's an example using hidden inputs:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b> SHARE PRICE</b></td>
        <td>$43.93</td>
        <td>$43.87</td>
        <td>$26.33</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h3>Important information that you should know about these stocks: </h3>
<ul>
    <li>0.1% of the trade value if the total trade value is less than $10,000</li>
    <li>0.08% of the trade value if the total trade value is greater than or equal to $10,000</li>
    <li>The minimum commission is $5</li>
</ul>

<form name="calculator">
    <input type="hidden" id="price1" value="43.93" />
    <input type="hidden" id="price2" value="43.87" />
    <input type="hidden" id="price3" value="26.33" />
    <p> Enter the number of Oracle Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input1"></p> <br>
    <p> Enter the number of Microsoft Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input2"></p> <br>
    <p> Enter the number of Symantec Corporation stocks you wish to purchase!: <input type="text" id="input3"></p> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Add!" onclick="javascript:sumUp()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sumUp() {
        var total = (document.getElementById("price1").value * document.getElementById("input1").value) + (document.getElementById("price2").value * document.getElementById("input2").value) + (document.getElementById("price3").value * document.getElementById("input3").value)
        alert("Your total is: $" + total);
    }
</script>
```

Here's the code for putting the total into a textbox. This would go at the end of your form and replace the `<script>` block from the first example.

```
<p>Your total is: $<input type="text" id="total" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sumUp() {
        var total = (document.getElementById("price1").value * document.getElementById("input1").value) + (document.getElementById("price2").value * document.getElementById("input2").value) + (document.getElementById("price3").value * document.getElementById("input3").value)
        document.getElementById("total").value = total;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I think this works. But the answer is given in a prompt, how do I convert into a text box? do i follow what i did for the previous one?

Comment: @Mary you can use .value dom propert to insert data into textarea

Comment: i'm sorry to bother. but it's not working. Maybe i'm doing it wrong. The total is still popping up as an alert.

Comment: should i change the alert part in alert("Your total is: $" + total);

Comment: @Mary Yes, you'll need to replace the alert(...) line with whatever code you want to use to put your total value onto the page (whether it's into a text box using .value, or another HTML element using .innerText or .innerHTML).

Comment: can't get it right. Now I've got the textbook next to the "ADD" clicker but the total is not being written there.

Comment: @Mary I've added another example that outputs to a textbox instead of an alert for you.

Comment: Oh. Now it works. Thank you so much. I was already starting to lose some of my patience since I've been working on this assignment for about 3hrs. Still have more to do. Than you so much. Is it ok if I keep on bothering you to help me with the other calculations if i am unable to figure it out on my own?