# else and if statements with commission

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

#### Given these three statements:

1. 0.1% of the trade value if the total trade value is less than $10,000
2. 0.08% of the trade value if the total trade value is greater than or equal to $10,000
3. The minimum commission is $5

How do I go about calculating the commission statement?? The answer should be given in a textbox next to the button "commission %"

Comment: Do you already have some code that you could show?

Comment: @MaxwellS [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29037916/1169519)...

Comment: @Mary, please post the entirety of code including the section with the button (lacking from original code in your post).

Comment: var trade_value = (amount1*price1) + (amount2*price2) + (amount3*price3)
 
 if (trade_value<10000)
 {
 commission=trade_value*0.001;// 0.1% of trade value
 }
 else 
 {
 commission=trade_value*0.0008;// 0.08% of trade value
 }
  commission +=5; // commission= commission +.5;

  var total= commission+trade_value;
  alert("Your trade value is: " + trade_value);
  alert("Your commission is: " + commission);
  alert("Your total price for the stocks you've choosen is: " + total);

Comment: I need to make changes into this. Right now, the answers show as prompts but now my assignment is to show them in a box after I click their corresponding buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var commission;
if(totalTradeValue < 10000)
    commission = tradeValue * .1;
else
    commission = tradeValue * .08;

if(commission < 5)
    commission = 5.0;
```

Then just set the text of your textBox to `commission`.

### EDIT

```
<input type="text" id="totalTradeValue" placeholder="Total Trade Value" />
<input type="text" id="tradeValue" placeholder="This Trade Value" />
<input type ="button" value="Calculate" onclick="multiply()" />
<input type="text" id="total_commission" placeholder="Total Commission"/>
```

...

```
function multiply() {
    var commission;
    var totalTradeValue = document.getElementById('totalTradeValue').value;
    var tradeValue = document.getElementById('tradeValue').value;

    if(totalTradeValue < 10000)
        commission = tradeValue * .1;
    else
        commission = tradeValue * .08;

    if(commission < 5)
        commission = 5.0;

    document.getElementById('total_commission').value = commission;
}
```

See [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scmgj9ce/11/) for a working example.

Comment: I have:input type="button" value="Commission %" onclick="javascript:multiply()" />
 <p> <input type="text" id="total_commission" /></p>

Answer (score 0):

**Clarification Required:** Do you want a textbox or just a box? Because textbox are editable. Also do yu want the textbox to be disabled before the button is clicked?

**Possible answer based on my assumptions:** Let's say you are taking trade value in html form variable tradeVal, and you may have code something like:

```
<input type="text" name="tradeVal" />
<button name="commission" onclick="calculate(tradeVal)" />
<input type="text" name="commissionVal" id="commissionVal">
```

Try with JS function as follows:

```
function calculate(tradeVal) {
      var commission = 5;
      if(tradeVal < 10000) {
            commission = tradeVal * .1;
      } else {
            commission = tradeVal * .08;
      }
      if(commission < 5) {
            commission = 5;
      }
      document.getElementById("commisssionVal").value = commission;
}
```

Tell me if you want something else than this.

**EDIT:**

```
function multiply() { 
    var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
    var commission;
    if(total < 10000) {
        commission = total * 0.001;
    } else { 
        commission = total * 0.0008;
    }
    if(commission < 5) {    //set minimum commission to $5
        commission = 5;
    }
    var total_commission =commission+total; 
    document.getElementById("commisssion").value = total_commission; 
}
```

**Suggestion**: I think you are totally new to this stuff. Have look at [this to  learn from basics](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: It's not showing up the commission. I know how to get it but in alert prompts but my assignment now is asking for the commission to be shown in a box

Comment: <input type="button" value="Commission %" onclick="javascript:muliply()" />
 <p> <input type="text" id="commission" /></p>

Comment: function multiply()
   {
  
  if(total < 10000)
  {
   commission = document.getElementById("total").value * 0.001;// 0.1% of trade value
  }
  else
  {
   commission = document.getElementById("total").value * 0.0008;// 0.08% of trade value
  }
   commission +=5; // commission= commission +.5'
   
   var total_commission =commission+total;
      document.getElementById('commisssionVal').value = commission;
 }

Comment: I think you are doing a little bit wrong. You say minimum commission is $5. But you are adding $5 to each result which shouldn't happen. Instead the commission will be $5 only if after calculation it is less than $5. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much. I saw your reply late but I was able to figure out the rest on my own

Comment: You can accept answer if you find it useful. Thanks!